# Integrating Selenium Junit tests with silk central efficently

Tags: junit, selenium-webdriver, junit4, silk-central

I'm able to run simple Selenium Junit Test case from Silk Central test management tool. Now I want to design selenium framework to work with Silk Central. Please let me know if any one is using silk central to run their selenium scripts designed in junit.

Please find my questions below:

1.How to automatically add the captured screenshot via Selenium webdriver to Run details section of Silk central Junit Test case.

2.How to automatically add my own custom defined log4j file to Run details section of Silk central Junit Test case.

Please help me guys i'm unable to find the answers.

Comment: Begging hardly ever works on SO. Please have a careful read through [Ask].

Comment: SiKing, I dono what's wrong with my question it's pretty straight forward. Let me know what additional details could be added.

Comment: Are you able to get Silk to run *any* JUnit test? Show your code if not. Can you add log4j to that? Show your code if not. Can you add Selenium to that? Show your code if not. Can you add screenshots to that? Show your code if not.

Answer (score 1):

Silk Central provides several parameters and information as a Java System property.

In your case, you need the value of the system property `#sctm_test_results_dir` in your JUnit test. The system property provides the path information of the folder, where all result files are collected after the run was finished.

With this folder information available in your JUnit test, you can place all your files there and they are automatically collected by Silk Central and are available in your test results.

(There are more parameters available for tests, just check the documentation topic 'Accessing Silk Central Parameters through Java System Properties')

BTW, we have releases a blog post on Selenium and Silk Central this week, just for your information: https://community.microfocus.com/borland/test/silk_central/b/weblog/archive/2015/06/10/test-management-for-selenium-tests-with-silk-central.aspx